# c# Linq get exact value

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I need to compare the exact string values with the database.

```
  e.g. string vals = "bicycle_store,clothing_store"
```

in the database i have other values containing word "store" e.g. electronics_store

when I execute the below linq it finds all contains "store" word. How can I update the linq so it only sets "selected = true" to what is been sent

```
        return (from x in _ctx.Category
                select new CategoryVM
                {
                    Text = x.Text,
                    Value = x.Value,
                    Selected = vals.Contains(x.Value) == true ? true : false

                }).ToList();
```

Comment: `string vals = "bicycle_store,clothing_store"` are there 2 values in this one string? Are the values always separated by a comma? Will a value ever contain a comma itself?

Comment: `== true ? true : false` is redundant.  Just remove it entirely.

Comment: @Quantic it can have more than 2 values in one string. Always separated by a comma. No comma inside the value.

Comment: 1) You should be able to get to each 'value' by splitting on comma: `vals.Split(',')`, 2) After splitting you don't need to use `Contains` if you want exact match, just do an equality check with `==`, and you can iterate the list to find any match using LINQ's [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns true if anything matches the condition: `Selected = vals.Split(',').Any(y=>y==x.Value)`. You may have to `string.Trim()` out whitespace.. depends more on your supposed "comma separated list of values".

Comment: Thank you @Quantic and Gert Arnold works as expected. You are using .Any() and he is using .Contains(). Which one should I use? Please explain the difference? In what scenario I should be using .any() or .contains()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split the values first:

```
string vals = "bicycle_store,clothing_store";
string[] values = vals.Split(',');

return (from x in _ctx.Category
        select new CategoryVM
        {
            Text = x.Text,
            Value = x.Value,
            Selected = values.Contains(x.Value)
        }).ToList();
```

This will translate into a SQL `IN` statement.

Comment: Thank you it works as expected. I wasnt able to tag you above. @Quantic code also works with Any() and you are using Contains(). Can you please explain difference?  In what scenario I should be using .any() or .contains()

Comment: @Ben I don't think there's a difference other than `Contains()` is cleaner than what I did (may be faster too..). [`Contains(x.Value)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) searches the input list for an element that equals `x.Value`, if it finds one it returns `true`. `Any(listToSearch, searchCondition)` on the other hand doesn't search for an element that equals a value, instead it searches *whatever condition you give it*, but I happen to gave it an equivalent condition of "search for an element that equals `x.Value`". In the end I would use `Contains()`.

Comment: I can't explain it fully in a few words, but `Contains` is better in translation to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use `where`:

```
return (from x in _ctx.Category
        where vals.Contains(x.Value)
        select new CategoryVM
        {
            Text = x.Text,
            Value = x.Value
        }).ToList();
```

---

If you want to limit the output to the given input(s) *exactly*, do not use a single string. `String.Contains` will return true if a given value is within the string at all, so `"bicycle_store".Contains("store")` will return true, since the word "store" exists within the word "bicycle_store".

Instead, use a string array. A `Contains` on an array will only return true if the string matches one of the elements exactly.

```
string[] valsArray = vals.Split(',');

return (from x in _ctx.Category
        where valsArray.Contains(x.Value)
        select new CategoryVM
        {
            Text = x.Text,
            Value = x.Value
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: this still returns other records containing "store word" in the value

Comment: @Ben What do you mean? What is the actual value of the `x.Value`s? Which values would you want to include or exclude for a given `vals`? Give us some sample data to work with.

Comment: @Ben Do you mean that you only want values that are, for example, `bicycle_store` or `clothing_store` and not ones that are merely `store`?